# How to access which stack item was pressed with kivymd FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial?

Tags: python, kivy, floating-action-button

I want to use KivyMDs FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial, with something different happening depending on which stack button is pressed. Right now, I'm just trying to print which button was pressed.

I've found outdated information from tutorials, but it looks like the current way to set a function on the button press is:

```
on_press_stack_button: root.callback(self)
```

then in my .py file I have

```
def callback(self, instance):
    print(instance.icon)
```

but no matter which stack icon I choose, the result that's printed is always 'plus' (the root icon)

I'm guessing this is because I'm passing self into the callback function, but what else am I supposed to pass to access the actual button that's clicked? I can't find any examples in the docs, and all the tutorials I find say to use

'''
callback: callback
'''
instead of on_press_stack_button:

but using callback doesn't print anything at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering about this too and I developed a method on my own. You can use this code as the number of buttons cannot be large and we already have to assign a different function to each button we add:

```
def callback(self, instance):
    self.speed_dial_buttons = [button for button in instance.children if isinstance(button, MDFloatingBottomButton)]
    if self.speed_dial_buttons[0] and self.speed_dial_buttons[1] is not None:
            first_button = self.speed_dial_buttons[0]
            second_button = self.speed_dial_buttons[1]
            first_button.on_release = on_press_first_button
            second_button.on_release = on_press_second_button
```